# Python: how to map one list and one list of list together

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip, list-comprehension

So I'm trying to get rid of some nested loops through map() and have trouble with a specific case.

I have two lists:

List1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

List2 = [[1, 2, 3], [5], [1, 6], [1, 0, 9, 10], [1, 5, 2]]

So basically list1 and list 2 are the same lengths, but list 2 is a list of lists of variable lengths.

I want to call some function on the equivalent of;

(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,5), (3,1), (3,6), (4,1), (4,0), (4,9) (4,10), (5,1), (5,5), (5,2)

using map. The first parameter of the tuple is from List1 and the second one is from the i'th equivalent of list1 on list2, with the sublist expanded.

so right now I have:

map(function, zip(list1, list2))

but I cannot see how I could expand list2 to get what I just described. I think it might involve list comprehensions, but I'm having a little trouble and trial and error didn't get me very far.

Another question is, if the inner function in this nested loop is susceptible to get called millions of times, will map() be significantly faster than just a for loop?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need `[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,5), (3,1), (3,6), (4,1), (4,0), (4,9) (4,10), (5,1), (5,5), (5,2)]` to be produced or..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its simple with list comprehension, like this

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [[1, 2, 3], [5], [1, 6], [1, 0, 9, 10], [1, 5, 2]]
print [(item1, s) for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2) for s in item2]
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 0), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 1), (5, 5), (5, 2)]
```

This oneliner is just a short version of

```
result = []
for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
    for s in item2:
        result.append((item1, s))
```

Comment: That works great - I'll take some time to study your answer and understand it, thanks. Do you think doing it in such a way can benchmark faster than the nested for loops for large lists? Also, I cannot seem to be able to accept an answer yet (account too new I guess), but this one works great :) Thanks again!

Comment: @JustinNelligan Dont worry, you should be able to accept after 15-20 minutes of posting the question. Pleas stay calm and accept this answer, if it really helps you :)

Comment: Incorporated to the real code (not just the toy example), works like a charm. Benchmarking right now (and still trying to wrap my mind around this one liner :))

Comment: @JustinNelligan Thanks for accepting and please check the expanded version of that oneliner.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions or lambda functions can help, but the solution will be too lengthy and unreadable. Probably a naive loop is better?

```
def join(list1, list2):
    for head, tail in zip(list1, list2):
        for thing in tail:
            yield (head, thing)
```

This is a generator. You can use it the following way:

```
pairs = join(list1, list2)
for pair in pairs:
    # do anything with pair
```

Or you want to store this right in memory instead of this incremental generator?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using itertools (no temporary list in memory):

```
from itertools import *
a = chain.from_iterable( product([i], j) for i, j in izip( List1, List2 ) )
```

You can transform this in a list using :

```
list(a)
```

Or just walk elements using a loop.

Comment: I can confirm that this one also works fine - accepted the other answer because the post was about list comprehension, but this one might save memory, will benchmark :) Thanks!

Comment: This is about list comprehension too. ;)

Comment: @JustinNelligan, the question specifically referred to `map` and didn't even mention list comprehensions.  So I'm a little confused why you say it's about list comprehension.